# Trait Bound f64: scale_info::TypeInfo Is Not Satisfied

Tags: substrate-node-template, rust

I'm working on a Substrate-based blockchain project and I've run into an issue related to type information and encoding. Specifically, I'm trying to use an f64 field within a struct that also uses Substrate's TypeInfo trait, but I'm getting a compilation error.

Here's a simplified version of my struct:

```
#[derive(Clone, Encode, Decode, PartialEq, RuntimeDebug, TypeInfo, MaxEncodedLen)]
#[scale_info(skip_type_params(T))]
pub struct LabelInfo<AccountId, Hashing, Balance> {
    pub owner: AccountId,
    pub public_key: BoundedVec<u8, ConstU32<128>>,
    pub reputation: f64,
    pub stake: Balance,
    pub staking_address: BoundedVec<u8, ConstU32<128>>,
    pub status: RegisterStatus,
}
```

The error message I'm getting is:

> the trait bound `f64: scale_info::TypeInfo` is not satisfied

The compiler also suggests that several other types do implement `TypeInf`o, such as `i128`, `i64`, `u128`, and `u64`.

How can I resolve this issue? Can `f64` be made to satisfy `TypeInfo`, or is there an alternative approach to achieve a similar outcome?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We normally never use floats in the runtime because of their possible interdeminism.
This is why `TypeInfo` is not default implemented for floats.
You can use [`PerBill`](https://docs.rs/sp-runtime/latest/sp_runtime/struct.Perbill.html) or any of the other [`PerThing`](https://docs.rs/sp-runtime/latest/sp_runtime/trait.PerThing.html) implementations to deterministically represent fractions within the range `[0, 1]`.
For normal fractions there is [`FixedI128`](https://docs.rs/sp-runtime/latest/sp_runtime/struct.FixedI128.html) and alike: [`FixedPointNumber`](https://docs.rs/sp-runtime/latest/sp_runtime/trait.FixedPointNumber.html).